# FingerPrint Authentication in Xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-fingerprint-api

I am having a login form and implementing fingerprint authentication.
I have the following code but the app crashes suddenly.

Button in xml file:

```
<Button Text="Scan Fingerprint" Clicked="FingerPrint_clicked"/>
```

Code behind this:

```
public async void FingerPrint_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
        var scanResult = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync("Show your fingerprint", cancellationToken);
        if(scanResult.Authenticated)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(null, "done", "ok");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert(null, "failed", "ok");
        }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(()=> CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
```

Added fingerprint in android.manifest file
and set fingerprint in emulator too

Upon clicking the button for fingerprint test, the app crashes suddenly.

Comment: did you follow all the instructions in the docs?  Have you tried trapping the exception that causes the crash?  Have you checked the stack trace for the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding this line to MainActivity.cs file:

```
 CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```